# What are sum of Rust types + lifetime?

Tags: rust

There's a trait that does this:

```
pub trait Device<'a> {
    type RxToken: RxToken + 'a;
    type TxToken: TxToken + 'a;
```

What dos this mean? Why not `type RxToken: RxToken<'a>`?

Comment: Such a constraint means that the concrete type of the associated type `RxToken` has to be boundet by a lifetime. The trait `RxToken` may have no lifetime constraints at all (and may not even need them). Also the associated type `RxToken` is not limited to lifetime bounded types (such as `&'a Type`), types with longer lifetime or owned types `Type` (since owned types satisfy every lifetime) are also qualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see an example:

```
trait SayHello {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}

pub trait Device<'a> {
    type MyType : SayHello + 'a;
}
```

As you see, `SayHello` itself does not know anything about lifetime constraints, but `MyType` is constrained to satisfy `SayHello` and must be valid for lifetime `'a`.

In contrast, consider

```
trait SayHello {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}

pub trait Device2<'a> {
    type MyType : SayHello;
}
```

Here, `Device2` has no lifetime requirements for `MyType` - it only needs to satisfy `SayHello`.